# Merge edges after loop cut

Tags: modeling, extrude

I used loop cut several times to turn a big box into a room. However now that I'm happy with the room shape I want to remove some of these edges.

For example see the highlighted edges in the image below, it shows how I want to merge all the edges on a single face so that it's easier to extend that wall outward later if I want.

[image: vertices to merge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either press Ctrl+X or X > dissolve edges. This will remove the edges but keep the faces. You can also select multiple faces and press F to dissolve them

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYehG.jpg

Comment: thank you!!  works perfectly.